# Installing numba and llvmlite Python on Windows 10 fail

Tags: python, windows, numba, llvmlite

Installing numba and llvmlite Python on Windows 10 failure

I have tried to install Python numba on  Windows 10 using

pip install numba

with partial success, but a failure installing llvmlite

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\users\paul\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from numba) (1.19.2+mkl)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\paul\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from numba) (49.2.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: numba, llvmlite
  Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for numba: filename=numba-0.51.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=2173229 sha256=249a12f2e1436ac244e2730f6e7ddb5bd53413460dcbdc4ed4e6aeebbf16d6ce
  Stored in directory: c:\users\paul\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\0a\51\41\9f5a61bcd9d25271d7021e05cbabcd574fb3d534d07654b780
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
      Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
      the following names:

        LLVMConfig.cmake
        llvm-config.cmake

      Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
      "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
      provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Doesn't know where LLVM is installed?

So I used Windows Environment editor to add LLVM_DIR with value C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-9.3.0-llvm-10.0.0-mingw-w64-7.0.0-r4\mingw64\lib\cmake\llvm

in the hope that it will use one of the four Clang versions that I have installed at C:\LLVM\clang-1100, C:\LLVM\clang-1000 ...
latest binary is C:\LLVM\clang-1100\LLVM\bin

I also have VS 1017 and 1019 installed, and all compilers are working OK from other IDEs and builds.

and downloaded the most recent wheel

llvmlite-0.34.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl

and added LLVM_DIR to system PATH

C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-9.3.0-llvm-10.0.0-mingw-w64-7.0.0-r4\mingw64\lib\cmake\llvm

This allows it to more nearly work, but fails using MSVC

```
   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(399,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvvf77_z\llvmlite\ffi\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(399,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvvf77_z\llvmlite\ffi\build\llvmlite.vcxproj]
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\winlibs64_stage\custombuilt\lib\libffi.dll.a' [C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvvf77_z\llvmlite\ffi\build\llvmlite.vcxproj]
    Trying generator 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvvf77_z\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvvf77_z\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 179, in main
        main_win32()
      File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xvvf77_z\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 94, in main_win32
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '--build', build_dir, '--config', config])
      File "c:\users\paul\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', 'C:\\Users\\Paul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xvvf77_z\\llvmlite\\ffi\\build', '--config', 'Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    error: command 'c:\\users\\paul\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\paul\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Paul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xvvf77_z\\llvmlite\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Paul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xvvf77_z\\llvmlite\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l4absc_g\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\paul\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\llvmlite' Check the logs for full command output.
```

This suggests that the output folder location is not specified, or that VS incremental build option is not set to 'not used'.

Or that I should use an LLVM version, but I don't know how to specify which one, and not use VS2017.

Suggestions how to get out of this rabbit hole most welcome ;-)

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to install `librosa` but I get stack with this error, but I managed to solve it with this:

- first I download the last version of llvmlite [Here](https://pypi.bartbroe.re/llvmlite/)
- than I run the following command:

> `pip install llvmlite-0.35.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`

- next for all packages need by librosa I install them as follow:

> `pip install --no-deps packageName`

- or just for more sample do as follow :

> `pip install librosa --ignore-installed llvmlite`